# Why are after training 5-state HMM only few entries of transition matrix left greater than zero?

Tags: machine-learning, hidden-markov-model

I try to create the speech recognition system based on 5-state HMM + Multivariate Gaussian function. I use my own feature vector derived from MFCC (Mel-frequency cepstral coefficients). The problem is that after training only a few entries of the HMM transition matrix are left greater then zero. It should be mentioned that only states 2 -- 4 can emit observation. States 1 and 5 help connecting model with other models to make a chain.
The initial matrix:

$$\left[ \begin{array}{ccccc} 
0.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
0.0 & 0.6 & 0.4 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
0.0 & 0.0 & 0.6 & 0.4 & 0.0 \\
0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.7 & 0.3 \\
0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0
\end{array} \right]$$

Matrix after model training on phoneme "a" samples is looking like that:

$$\left[ \begin{array}{ccccc} 
0.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
0.0 & 0.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
0.0 & 0.0 & 0.8910256 & 0.1089744 & 0.0 \\
0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 1.0 \\
0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0
\end{array} \right]$$

The training corpus consists of 187 sequences with about 10 vectors in average in every sequence. 
The performance of such model is quite poor.

So what might be the main reasons for such sparse transition matrix after model training?

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: The first thing I would point out is if a transition has zero probability initially it will always remain zero, but maybe you know this. Have you taken care to avoid numerical underflow issues? If yes to both these questions, then I would guess the model is just too limited (it can only ever transition from state $j$ to $j$ or $j+1$ by construction).

Comment: Well I do know that zero probabilities can't increase. The model is trained using HTK [link] (http://htk.eng.cam.ac.uk/), so numerical errors are unlikely since even warning messages was not being issued during the training process. In addition matrix looks much better if I use pure MFCC. I guess something is wrong with feature vector. The question is what?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what they are. Maybe a problem with how are you initializing the emission distributions? Looking at your initial matrix it is clear how you "want" the HMM to work. I might try something like 1.) fit the parameters of a multivariate Gaussian to the observations in the beginning of the sequences, 2.) initialize the emission distribution of state 2 with these parameters, 3.) repeat this for states 3 and 4 using the middle and end of the sequences respectively. It could also be that the emission distribution you're using is a poor match for your new features.

Comment: Well, I'm using the kOPLS (kernel orthonormalized partial least squares) with Gaussian kernel extracted from pure MFCC. On toy 2D data it yields nice visual data separation. But your idea about incompatibility
of such kind of feature vector with Gaussian emission probability looks for me quite plausible. So I am going to work out it. Thank you very much.